# Cannot access the file ASP.NET and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, ioexception, streamwriter

I need some help. I'm trying to write/create a log file for error logging of our asp.net web app. Previously my code is working without issue, but now I encountered an error *"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"* even though I did not change anything in my code. But in any case I need to resolve this issue. Please help. What's wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
        StreamWriter file;
        if (logDetails.User.Length == 0)
        {
            logDetails.User = "Administrator";
        }

        string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, appFile) + "_" + logDetails.User + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            file = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}\t\t\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t\t\t\t\t\t{4}\t\t\t\t{5}", "DATE", "PRIORITY", "SEVERITY", "MESSAGE", "EXCEPTION TYPE");
            builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            file = File.AppendText(fileName);  //**exception thrown here**
        }

        builder.Append(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t\t{5}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), logDetails.detail1, logDetails.detail2, logDetails.detail3+ logDetails.detail4, logDetails.detail5));

        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.Append(String.Format("STACKTRACE"));
        builder.AppendLine(logDetails.StackTrace);
        file.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(builder));
        file.Close();
```

Comment: Is multi-threading involved? Your code will fail if it is called from different threads. Better keep the file handle open througout the runtime of yor App. Also make sure your app is running only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}\t\t\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t\t\t\t\t\t{4}\t\t\t\t{5}", "DATE", "PRIORITY", "SEVERITY", "MESSAGE", "EXCEPTION TYPE");
    builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
builder.Append(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t\t{5}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), logDetails.detail1, logDetails.detail2, logDetails.detail3+ logDetails.detail4, logDetails.detail5));

builder.AppendLine();
builder.Append(String.Format("STACKTRACE"));
builder.AppendLine(logDetails.StackTrace);

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
{
    sw.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `using` and make sure the file is not physically opened somewhere.